# Is this the correct way to use an Expression<Func<string, string>>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Currently, I'm in the process of writing custom controls for MVC, thus extending the `HtmlHelper`.
I'm working with `Expression<T>` here, but I'm relatively new to it.

Altough my code is working, I just want to verify is this is correct.

I'm rendering a control, and I can add attributes to the rendered control in a fluent way.
The way to add an attribute to my control is with the following code:

```
.Attributes(style => "width: 100%;")
```

When I want to use multiple attributes on my rendered control, this method can be called multiple times:

```
.Attributes(style => "width: 100%;")
.Attributes(id => "renderedControl")
```

In order to render the attributes, I'm looking in the expression containing the attribute.

Here's the method signature that I use for adding attributes:

```
public IGridConstructor<TModel> Attributes(Expression<Func<string, string>> expression)
```

So, I'm passing an `Expression` containing a `Func<string, string>`.
The input parameter of the function is the name of the attribute while the output parameter is the value belonging to this attribute.

This does mean that the extression:

```
style => "width: 100%;"
```

Should render an attribute: `style="width: 100%"`

Now, I do have achieved that with the following code:

```
private void AddAttribute(Expression<Func<string, string>> expression)
{
    var propertyName = expression.Parameters[0].ToString();
    var propertyValue = expression.Compile()(string.Empty);

    GridAttributes.Add(propertyName, propertyValue);
}
```

Is this a correct approach to do so? I'm not happy with the `[0]` here.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Compiling expressions is expensive. Better not do it too often. I'd rather interpret the expression tree (it will be a single constant).

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. Mind providing me with a small sample on how to interpret the tree?

Comment: It seems like you're over-engineering this a little, what's wrong with a simple key-value pair: `.AddAttribute("style", "width: 100%")` or `.Attributes(new { style = "width: 100%", id = "something" })`?

Comment: You could also do it in the same way a lot of the MVC helpers do, using an anonymous object: `new { style = "width: 100%;", id = "renderedControl" }`

Comment: I know, but I wanted to use an expression. It's more fun to use :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an anonymous object, which would let you add multiple attributes rather than chaining your expressions.

```
private void AddAttributes(object attributes)
{
    foreach(var property in attributes.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        GridAttributes.Add(
            property.Name, 
            property.GetValue(attributes));
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
AddAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%;", id = "renderedControl" });
```

Comment: I know that that is a solution, but the question stated that I would like to use Expression{T}.

Comment: I realise that, but thought it was worth adding this anyway. Personally I feel like the expression method (while interesting) is a bit expensive and inflexible for this purpose.

Comment: I understand, but I just want to know if the usage of the Expression{T} is a correct approach here.

Comment: Well if it's working, it's not technically "wrong" :)